# Is ‘trumpeted’ giving the intended meaning in this context?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning

> This international accomplishments are often **trumpeted** by political officials
> as a cause for pride.

I want to say that political officials always mention those accomplishments as a source of pride. I intend *trumpeted* to convert that with some emphasis. Does it do that?

Answer (score 1):

Trumpeted is often used to mean bloviate. Talking something up in an over-the-top way. In your sentence above, it implies that the accomplishments are maybe not quite as good as the politicians say they are.

Comment: That is what I want it to imply actually.

Comment: Great! Happy to help!

Answer (score 0):

"Trumpet" is  perfect. Here's the confirmation.

> ([OALD](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/trumpet_2)) [transitive] **trumet**  to talk or write about something publicly in proud or enthusiastic way
>
> **trumpet something**
> • to trumpet somebody’s achievements
>
> **trumpet something as something**
> • Their marriage was trumpeted as the wedding of the year.

Comment: My understanding is that trumpet as a verb has a negative connotation. is it not so?

Comment: @R.S. Yes, trumpets are  "loud" instruments!

Comment: Thanks. I wasn't entirely sure OP wanted to convey a negative sense.